# Custom Labels Implementation and Use for iOS Apps

Tags: ios

I use Storyboards heavily for my iPhone development. To keep the Labels look the same I create custom UILabels and set the font and size in the custom classes. Then in the Storyboard I assign those classes to the labels displayed in the view.

This works fine but I have 4-5 different kind of labels which only differ by size or weight. How do I deal with this situation? Currently I have the following:

```
PrimaryLabel
PrimaryLabelBold
DescriptionLabel
DescriptionLabelSmall
DescriptionLabelBold
```

I think this is too much work and these have to be a better way!!

Answer (score 1):

No need to subclass `UILabel` so many times. Just create one subclass, like so:

**MyLabel.h**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyLabelStyle) {
    MyLabelStyleSmall,
    MyLabelStyleMedium,
    MyLabelStyleBig,
};

@interface MyLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic) MyLabelStyle style;

@end
```

**MyLabel.m**

```
#import "UILabel+Styles.h"

@implementation UILabel (Styles)

- (void)setStyle:(MyLabelStyle)style
{
    switch (style) {
        case MyLabelStyleSmall:
            self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            break;
        case MyLabelStyleMedium:
            self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
            break;
        case MyLabelStyleBig:
            self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
            break;
        default:
            self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

In your storyboard, set the style of a particular label using User Defined Runtime Attributes:

[image]

`2` corresponds to `MyLabelStyleBig`. Use strings instead of an enum if you want.

Comment: Thanks! Although that will work but still it is quite ugly since the numbers in the user defined attributes don't specify the meaning in real time. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @johndoe That's why I said you could use strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the UILabel class  and than create the constructor method in which you can define the type of label you want ie

```
PrimaryLabel
PrimaryLabelBold
DescriptionLabel
DescriptionLabelSmall
DescriptionLabelBold
```

For this you can create an enumeration depecting the types of Label's you want. Within the constructor method you can set this enum value.

Happy coding :)

Comment: The labels are set using the design view and not in code. They are set in the Storyboard designer.