# Easiest way to style the text of an UILabel in iOS7/iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm learning objective c a little bit to write an iPad app. I've mostly done some html5/php projects and learned some python at university. But one thing that really blows my mind is how hard it is to just style some text in an objective C label.

Maybe I'm coming from a lazy markdown generation, but really, if I want to let an UILabel look like:

> > **Objective:** Construct an *equilateral* triangle from the line segment AB.

In markdown this is as simple as:

`**Objective:** Construct an *equilateral* triangle from the line segment AB.`

Is there really no pain free objective C way to do this ? All the tutorials I read really wanted me to write like 15 lines of code. For something as simple as this.

So my question is, what is the easiest way to do this, if you have a lot of styling to do in your app ? Will styling text become more natural with swift in iOS8 ?

Comment: Yeah I think you would need 15ish lines of code... You'd probably have to make an attributed string for each style

Comment: What do you mean by lot of styling? Does it mean that much of your labels' styles would be different from each other? Or is there a set theme you'd like to follow throughout your app? Also, did you use Markdown as an example of ease of use, or do you actually want to use Markdown in your code?

Comment: No, there is definitely a theme. Mostly some bold/italic and color changes. It is easy if all the text in the UILabel has the same style, but I'm interested in what is the easiest way if only a couple of words in a UILabel text have a different styling. If I could use markdown, well that would be brilliant, but I'm just interested in a easy solution, doesn't have to be markdown.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25000864/1593651) if there's a general theme to your app. I'd suggested doing things manually using attributed strings, if there are substrings with different styles. If you're looking for a very easy to use Markdown parser to generate attributed strings, I suggest [the one that comes with NimbusKit](https://github.com/NimbusKit/markdown).

Comment: The 15 lines Objective-C will probably still run faster than your markdown, because that stuff is compiled into byte code and does not need to be parsed at runtime. There are pros and cons for both, obviously, but that's just the Objective-C approach to it.

Comment: There are libraries that might help. [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) springs to my mind; you can use it to transform HTML into attributed strings, for example, which might speed things up. Wouldn't surprise me if there was at least a partial library out there that did Markdown, too. (Looks like it's on the todo list for https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTMarkdownParser)

Comment: @vikingosegundo "Another is to, at some point in the not-too-distant future, provide input for DTCoreText to allow generating NSAttributedStrings directly from Markdown". (It's a markdown parser, but it doesn't hook into an attributed string generator yet.)

Comment: Hey, @90intuition, are you there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `NSAttributedString`'s `data:options:documentAttributes:error:` initializer (first available in iOS 7.0 SDK).

```
import UIKit

let htmlString = "<b>Objective</b>: Construct an <i>equilateral</i> triangle from the line segment AB."
let htmlData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let options = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
var error : NSError? = nil

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: options, documentAttributes: nil, error: &error)

if error == nil {
    // we're good
}
```

***Note:*** You might also want to include `NSDefaultAttributesDocumentAttribute` option in the `options` dictionary to provide additional global styling (such as telling not to use Times New Roman).

Take a look into **[NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)** for more information.

Comment: Oooh, that's a little hidden gem. +1

Comment: I haven't been able to get the `NSDefaultAttributesDocumentAttribute` to work with `NSHTMLTextDocumentType`. Is there some trick to get it to work, or does it only work with `NSPlainTextDocumentType`?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar frustrations while trying to use attributed text in Xcode, so I feel your pain. You can definitely use multiple `NSMutableAttributedtext`'s to get the job done, but this is very rigid.

```
UIFont *normalFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"..." size:20];
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"..." size:20];
UIFont *italicizedFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"..." size:20];
NSMutableAttributedString *total = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]init];

NSAttributedString *string1 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Objective"] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:boldFont}];

NSAttributedString *string2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@": Construct an "] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:normalFont}];

NSAttributedString *string3 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"equilateral "] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:italicizedFont}];

NSAttributedString *string4 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"triangle from the line segment AB."] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:normalFont}];

[total appendAttributedString:string1];
[total appendAttributedString:string2];
[total appendAttributedString:string3];
[total appendAttributedString:string4];

[self.someLabel setAttributedText: total];
```

Another option is to use `NSRegularExpression`. While this will require more lines of code, it is a more fluid way of bolding, changing color, etc from an entire string at once. For your purposes however, using the `appendAttributedString` will be the shortest way with a label.

```
    UIFont *normalFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"..." size:20];
    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithFamilyName:@"..." size: 20];
    UIFont *italicizedFont = [UIFont fontWithFamilyName:@"..." size: 20];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Objective: Construct an equilateral triangle from the line segment AB."] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:normalFont}];

    NSError *regexError;

    NSRegularExpression *regex1 = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"Objective"
                                                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexError];
    NSRegularExpression *regex2 = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"equilateral"
                                                                             options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexError];
    if (!regexError)
    {
        NSArray *matches1 = [regex1 matchesInString:[attributedString string]
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [[attributedString string] length])];
        NSArray *matches2 = [regex2 matchesInString:[attributedString string]
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [[attributedString string] length])];

        for (NSTextCheckingResult *aMatch in matches1)
        {
            NSRange matchRange = [aMatch range];
            [attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:boldFont}
                                      range:matchRange];
        }
        for (NSTextCheckingResult *aMatch in matches2)
        {
            NSRange matchRange = [aMatch range];
            [attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:italicizedFont}
                                      range:matchRange];

        }

    [self.someLabel setAttributedText: attributedString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the [akashivskyy’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25068643/1271826) (+1) with contemporary Swift syntax:

```swift
guard let data = htmlString.data(using: .utf8) else { return }

do {
    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(
        data: data,
        options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
        documentAttributes: nil
    )

    ...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```